# Add Y-Axis dynamically Chartjs

Tags: javascript, dynamic, chart.js, axis

I am trying to add a secondary dataset to a line chart that I have. I am easily able to add the data entries however how can I dynamically add a second scale on the right of the chart?

To add data I do:

```
function addDataset(){
    var dataset =  {
        label: response[0].yaxis,
        data: response.data,
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 5
    }

    mychart.data.datasets.push(dataset); 
}
```

As I said, this works for adding the actual data points, but how can I dynamically add a second Y-Axis on the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to provide an answer as I solved my own issue and in case anyone has a similar question.

What I ended up doing was pushing a completely new dataset that aligned with the Y-Axis.

```
myChart.data.datasets.push(createNewDataset('Your Label', '', YourArrayOfData, 0, 'y-axis-1'));
```

the important part for me was putting the y-axis-1 which set the new axis on the right hand side.